# Xamarin dynamic forms

Tags: xamarin, dynamic, view, binding, viewmodel

The idea is to create an app in Xamarin with dynamic forms. The form definition is taken from any source like local DB or Web API.
The definition contains the set of fields and theirs's default values.

Currently my question is about view model.
Let's say the situation is clear with a view. I mean that user controls can be added to a view programmatically based on the form definition.
But how view model should look like in this case?
As a set of dynamic properties ? How to support user controls binding to respective view model properties ?

Any ideas or links to respective articles are welcomed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: We need more details. What you have tried? Any code or any screenshot of result would be helpful.

Comment: I have not done anything yet. So I have nothing to share except my thoughts and questions. I am looking for any best practices or right way to do it currently.

Comment: Maybe the DynamicForms would be helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866878/11850033

Comment: Thank you, I have checked the link. Currently I am moving into the direction of predefined DataTemplate and dedicated view model for each required type of user control